# pkfix-helper shows METAFONT error (can't find file `ecsy')

Tags: errors, metafont

I tried to use `pkfix-helper`, but I get a strange error from METAFONT. I'm MiKTeX and all packages are updated to the newest version. What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads\temp>pkfix-helper file.ps file-helper.ps
Reading file.ps ... done.
Number of Type 3 fonts encountered in included documents: 0
Total number of Type 3 fonts encountered: 22
Bitmapped fonts are typeset at 300 DPI.
Finding character widths ... done.
Reading TFM files ... This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a\lasy12.mf
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\fikpa
rm.mf
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/cm\cmb
ase.mf)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\lcyrb
eg.mf)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\lklig
tbl.mf)
>> 0.12
>> "input ecsy"
! I can't find file `ecsy'.
<scantokens> input ecsy

<to be read again>
                   ;
use_driver->...#=pt#;pt#:=true_pt#;scantokens(ss);
                                                  pt#:=true_pt#;font_identif...
l.304 use_driver(fonteq)
                        ;
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<scantokens> input ecsy

<to be read again>
                   ;
use_driver->...#=pt#;pt#:=true_pt#;scantokens(ss);
                                                  pt#:=true_pt#;font_identif...
l.304 use_driver(fonteq)
                        ;
Transcript written on lasy12.log.

Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit)

(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a\lasy17.mf
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\fikpa
rm.mf
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/public/cm\cmb
ase.mf)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\lcyrb
eg.mf)
(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts/source/lh/base\lklig
tbl.mf)
>> 0.17
>> "input ecsy"
! I can't find file `ecsy'.
<scantokens> input ecsy

<to be read again>
[...]
```

Comment: I'm not able to find `input ecsy` in any file under `.../fonts/source/lh/` on my TeX distribution. Nor I can find `lasy12.mf` in `.../fonts/source/lh/lh-t2a/`

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your METAFONT sources. Current sources of the lh cyrillic fonts identified by the labels `Version 3.5 // Patchlevel=` (where the Patchlevel is 0, 1, or 2 depending on the file) or `3.5g` contain neither files like `lasy12.mf` or `lasy17.mf` nor the file `ecsy.mf`. I suggest updating your TeX distribution as a whole, or at least to upload up-todate lh cyrillic fonts.

BTW, `lasy12.mf` or `lasy17.mf` are non-standard fonts that can be build using the Sauter font building tools found in

https://ctan.org/pkg/sauterfonts

(LaTeX support for them is found in the package

https://ctan.org/pkg/sauter

). You probably need to install these packages on your computer to get the fonts `lasy12.mf` or `lasy17.mf`.

Comment: There aren't any updates available. I'll try to remove miktex completely and do a fresh reinstall.